# what is function redirect() in php

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use a code to connect gmail and get my friends list. In that code there is a function call

```
redirect('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token='. $oauth->rfc3986_decode($accrss_token['oauth_token']), 'location');
```

I've searched for function `redirect()` but didn't find it in the php manual. Is it a built in function in php?

The 2nd parameter is `'location'`  what is the use of that parameter?

Here is the function where it's used:

```
public function connect_google($oauth=null){

if(!$oauth)
{
    return null;
}
//create a gmailcontacts objects
$getcontact = new GmailGetContacts();
$accrss_token = $getcontact->get_request_token($oauth, false, true, true);

$this->ci->session->set_userdata('oauth_token', $accrss_token['oauth_token']);
$this->ci->session->set_userdata('oauth_token_secret', $accrss_token['oauth_token_secret']);
//redirect to google auth
redirect('https://www.google.com/accounts/OAuthAuthorizeToken?oauth_token='. $oauth->rfc3986_decode($accrss_token['oauth_token']), 'location');

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is part of the CodeIgniter URL helper. See:

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/helpers/url_helper.html

From the documentation:

> Does a "header redirect" to the URI specified. If you specify the full site URL that link will be build, but for local links simply providing the URI segments to the controller you want to direct to will create the link. The function will build the URL based on your config file values.

Answer (score 1):

As you've said, it isnt a built in function, so we dont know what it should look like.
However, considering the name i guess it should look like this:

```
function redirect($url, $header)
{
 header("$header: $url");
}
```

Since sending a `Location: {ur}` header will redirect your page to another.

Comment: I would have thought the function would include `exit` or `die` after setting the header. Maybe it also includes checking if headers have already been sent, etc, for improved error handling.

Answer (score 0):

Use `header`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php

```
header('Location: urlOfDestination');
```

Answer (score 0):

It is probably a user defined function. It probably works hand in hand with [`header()`](http://php.net/header) hence the name, the first parameter is the page to redirect to, and the second one is to tell the function that it is indeed a redirect to the `location`. Just check out the header function.